# Calling a python function from an AWS lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on an AWS lambda function that calls python functions and prints what my python function prints. This is my python function named "template_utils.py"

```
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
def create_aws_iam_policy_template(**kwargs):
  template_data = {}
  template_data["region"] = kwargs.get('region')
  template_data["instance_types"] = kwargs.get('instance_type')
  template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = kwargs.get('ebs_volume_size')
  template_data["meta_template_name"] = kwargs.get('meta_template_name')

  meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
  meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
  template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)
  return template_json  

template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
  region="us-east-2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size="20",
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template"
)

print(template_json)
```

This is my AWS lambda function:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from template_utils import create_aws_iam_policy_template 
import json

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        template_data = {}
        region = event.get('region')
        instance_type = event.get('instance_type')
        ebs_volume_size = event.get('ebs_volume_size')
    print(template_json)
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indentations? Also, what is the issue? Any errors?

Comment: Yeah I am getting an undefined variable for "tempalte_json" for my lambda-handler

Comment: What is `template_json` or what you think it should be in `print(template_json)`? Its not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have got an IAM policy and my python function prints "template_json" in a JSON format I want my lambda-handler to print that

Comment: So `create_aws_iam_policy_template` is not in your lambda? You can place it there, given you will also provide its dependencies (ninja2).

Comment: How do I place it there?, can I not just import create_aws_iam_policy_template from template_utils. Also, I have uploaded the zip file with all the files will that be enough for providing Jinja2